# Automapper - read properties with underscore as nested object

Tags: sql, orm, mapping, automapper, automapper-3

for example I have DB view that returns these columns:

```
Id int
Name nvarchar(200)
PrimaryAddress_Street nvarchar(200)
PrimaryAddress_City nvarchar(200)
```

And I would like to map it to my DTO:

```
public class Customer {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
  public string Street { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use AutoMapper to do it.
I have mapped `IDataRecord` to my DTO and then read it directly from ADO.NET `DbDataReader`:

```
CreateMap<IDataRecord, Customer>();
var result = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<Customer>>(reader);
```

It works for basic properties in `Customer` DTO. But of course nested `PrimaryAddress` property is left null because this underscore notation is not build in AutoMapper.

Do you have any ideas how to extend AutoMapper to support this?

Remark: We are using this notation because it works well with Entity Framework and I don't want to have different view for EF and for AutoMapper.